# Error: The network path was not found while connecting to SQL Server Express

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm getting an "The network path was not found" error with a ASP.Net web application while connecting to SQL Server Express database.

In the application, I have two databases: Via.DB.ViaContext and ViaOnline

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Via.ViaContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Via.DB.ViaContext;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ViaOnline;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/></connectionStrings>
```

ViaOnline is the name of my project, and ViaOnline database is created automatically by Entity Framework (code first) if it doesn't exist on SQLEXPRESS, and it stores the users. So for this database, I don't get an error.

But for Via.DB.ViaContext, when I try to access to data via:

```
using (var db = new ViaContext()) {
    roads = db.Roads.Where(r => r.Name.Contains(s)).ToList<Road>();
}
```

I get the error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

With inner exception:

> The network path was not found

It doesn't create it. And if I restore the database Via.DB.ViaContext from a backup, I can see it on SQLEXPRESS instance in SQL Management Studio, but I still get the error.

Have you got ideas on how to deal with this ?

Comment: Did you specify `Via.ViaContext` connection string in `ViaContext` constructor?

Comment: No I didn't. I just tried it and it works like a charm! Thank you very much